# Opencart reading data from a file

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, opencart

I am very new to open-cart.I have a task to read data from the file.

So i have made a function open-cart to read the file in model category.php

Code :

```
public function getFileData($category_id) {
    $file = fopen("temp.txt","r");
    $a = array();
    while(! feof($file))
    {
        array_push($a, fgetcsv($file));
    }
    fclose($file);
    return $a;
}
```

now when i call it from controller it gives me timeout error more than 60s. i increased the time out using set_time_limit but no effect.

But then i made a simple script to read file and it is reading it with in a milliseconds.
But same code is not working in opencart.

I tried Google but found nothing . i am sure that i am missing something.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: show the file path where have you declared this function and also from which controller you are calling it

Comment: function is in :  C:\wamp\www\dtd\catalog\model\catalog\category.php  Controler is in : C:\wamp\www\dtd\catalog\controller\product\product.php

Comment: Please copy the file to image folder with 777 permission (for testing) and change `fopen("temp.txt","r");` to `fopen(DIR_IMAGE."temp.txt","r");`.

Comment: @sankar Hi Thanks ,its working can you tell me the reason . now my files are present outside the open-cart folder means in www/files/temp.txt how will i read from there?

Comment: No need to put the files outside the opencart folder. The reasons may be:
1. File permission issue.
2. File location given was wrong. 

I'll add it as an answer, so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to try:

1. Check the file permission (test by giving 777 permission).
2. Verify the file path.
3. Give absolute path to the file by using the constants in config.php file. For example if the file is in `image/data` folder give the file path as "DIR_IMAGE."/data/temp.txt".
4. Confirm that the file exists by using php `file_exists` function: https://www.php.net/file_exists.

Have a nice day !!

Comment: Thanks you so much   can you tell me why it is necessary to give paths in config.php in open-cart?

Comment: The answer is simple - the opencart needs those values for its working. For example if you look at `catalog/controller/common/header.php`, you can see `if ($this->config->get('config_logo') && file_exists(DIR_IMAGE . $this->config->get('config_logo'))) {`. Is that clear now?